# How to get Bitmap byte count in API level 11?

Tags: android

There is a useful method `bitmap.getByteCount()` since API level 12. But how to get same value in API 11?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's best to just use the support library:

```
int bitmapByteCount=BitmapCompat.getAllocationByteCount(bitmap)
```

or, if you wish to do it yourself:

```
public static int getBitmapByteCount(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        return bitmap.getByteCount();
    return bitmap.getAllocationByteCount();
}
```

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned by dmon, according to the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428193/where-the-heck-is-bitmap-getbytecount) `bitmap.getByteCount()` is just a convenience method which returns `bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight()`. So you can use a custom method instead :

```
public static long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
}
```

Comment: Like the commenters said in that answer, you don't need the if-else block. Just use the else bit. That way you don't need AndroidVersion.